# Jbehave ExamplesTable array/list as parameter

Tags: java, bdd, jbehave

We have story files like so (say)

```
Given Something
Scenario Some scenario
When I do something blah blah
Then I get a bunch of stuff and the following data:
{transformer=FROM_LANDSCAPE}
|aField|aVal1|aVal2|aVal3|
|bField|bVal1|bVal2|bVal3|
|cField|cVal1|cVal2|cVal3|
```

Then in our steps class:

```
@Then("I get a bunch of stuff and the following data:$myData")
public void verifyData(ExamplesTable myData) {

    List<SomeDataClass> myDataList = myData.getRowsAs(SomeDataClass.class);

    // do something

}
```

And SomeDataClass typically looks like:

```
public class SomeDataClass {

    private int aField;
    private String bField;
    private String cField;

    // getters/setters ...

}
```

But I am in a situation where I have a data class like so:

```
public class NewDataClass {
    private int aField;
    private String bField;
    private Set<SomeObj> cField;

    //...

}
```

In this case I have a collection (set) of things as a field.  How can I represent this in the story syntax above using a table?  Maybe there's a better way?

Comment: Are you wanting to process one row of data iteratively, or the entire set of rows at once?  If the former, that's the standard behavior of `Examples:` but your syntax would need to change.

Comment: I don't think it matters as long as I have access to all the data in the steps class

Answer (score 1):

JBehave supports [mapping parameters to custom types](https://jbehave.org/reference/stable/tabular-parameters.html).
The provided example will have the following syntax.

> Story file:

```
Given Something
Scenario Some scenario
When I do something blah blah
Then I get a bunch of stuff and the following data:
{transformer=FROM_LANDSCAPE}
|aField|aVal1|aVal2|aVal3|
|bField|bVal1|bVal2|bVal3|
|cField|cVal1|cVal2|cVal3|
```

> Step implementation:

```
@Then("I get a bunch of stuff and the following data:$myData")
public void verifyData(List<NewDataClass> myData) {
    // step logic
    // ...
}
```

> NewDataClass:

```
import org.jbehave.core.annotations.AsParameters;

@AsParameters
public class NewDataClass {
    private int aField;
    private String bField;
    private Set<SomeObj> cField;

    // getters & setters
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I think your answer much more directly addresses the poster's question, so I upvoted it.

Answer (score 0):

Example story file snippet:

```
Given I am on the add a new user page
When I enter <firstName> <lastName> <address> <city> <state> and <zip>
And I click the Ok button
Then the new user is added

Examples:
firstName|lastName|address        |city    |state|zip
Bill     |Hileman |123 Main Street|Yourtown|FL   |12345
Art      |VanDelay|321 Elm Drive  |MyTown  |PA   |54321
```

steps file code:

```
@When("I enter <firstName> <lastName> <address> <city> <state> and <zip>")
public void whenIEnterdata(@Named("firstName") String firstName,
                           @Named("lastName") String lastname,
                           @Named("address") String address,
                           @Named("city") String city,
                           @Named("state") String state,
                           @Named("zip") String zip) {
    // your step code here
}
```